# Keep Google Maps from reloading in JqueryMobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps api in my jquerymobile/phonegap project. Currently if you go to the map "page" and change the zoom level, drag the map around, etc and then navigate away and back to the map page it doesnt save its state, it reloads the map. I have tried using dom-cache `<div data-role="page" id="map" data-dom-cache="true">` but that didn't seem to help at all.

How can I save the map "state" and avoid reload when navigating away and back?

**Requested code**

```html
    <div data-role="page" id="map" data-dom-cache="true">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
            <h1>HoneySpot</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0;">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>                 
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-id="mainnav" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#top" data-icon="arrow-u" id="top">Top</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#add" data-icon="plus" id="add">Add</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#map" data-icon="search" id="search" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#feed" data-icon="bars" id="feed">Feed</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#profile" data-icon="gear" id="profile">Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /navbar -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

js

```js
$(document).on('pageshow', '#map', function (event) {
    max_height();
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{'enableHighAccuracy':true,'timeout':20000});
});
function onSuccess(position) {       
    var minZoomLevel = 15;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: minZoomLevel,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Show some code. Maybe you create your map on event 'pageshow'?

Comment: Thank you for leading me in the right direction. I changed it to `$(document).ready(function(event) {` and it works great now!

Comment: No problem. You can post the answer to your problem yourself and accept it, so you can help others with the same problem and of course increase your karma points.

Comment: Hmm, now that I think about it, are you sure that that is the way to go? If you go with 'document ready' then you will calculate the position only one time, you will have to refresh every time you want to recalculate the position. If that is what you want then never mind this comment.

Comment: Thanks alkis. I plan on having a button that the user can refresh the search.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for leading me in the right direction. I changed it to $(document).ready(function(event) { and it works great now!